# How to select a single value from a table, to use for comparison(greater than/less than)?

Tags: sas

I am handing over some code to a colleague, which is to be run daily to generate reports.

Once every month a new cycle starts, and we have to update the code for cycle_start_date

```
data mtd_table;
set ytd_table;
where entry_date> '10Mar2021'd; /*different every month*/
run;
```

Since he'll be running them from now on, along with other reports from other teams, I don't want to bother him every month to tweak the code. So I devised this:

i run(once a month)

```
data shared1.cycle_start_date;
cycle_start_date='10Mar2021'd;
run;
```

he runs(everyday)

```
data mtd_table;
set ytd_table;
where entry_date>/*(select cycle_start_date from shared1.cycle_start_date)*/;
run;
```

I'm not sure how to correctly implement this *(select cycle_start_date from shared1.cycle_start_date)* part, since it is from proc sql. Would appreciate help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you store program parameters in a data set (called *control data*) one use case is having later code extract the values into macro variables, at which point other code can resolve the macro variable for replacement at (automatic) step compile and run time.  Two ways to extract values into macro variables are:

- `Proc SQL`, `SELECT ... INTO :<macro-variable>`, and
- `DATA _NULL_`, `CALL SYMPUT(<macro-variable>, <data step expression>);`

Don't forget, macro resolution replaces the macro variable as **source code text**.  Dates in macro variables can be either the SAS data value (the text representation of a SAS date integer) or part of a date literal (the text `<dd-mon-yyyy>`) that would be resolved as source date literal `"&<macro-variable>"D` when to be utilized as a date value.  The date literal part is used when you want to show the date value as human readable in when output; for example: `TITLE "cycle start: &cycle_start_date";`

---

**Control data (you)**

Rebuild or edit values in data set (name it parameters to be more useful)

```
data shared1.parameters;
  cycle_start_date = '10Mar2021'd;  * stored as a SAS date value (integer);
run;
```

*Note: Some control data layouts use a name/value organization and has one row per parameter.*

**Other**

Extract date value as SAS date value text, and as date literal text portion and use.

```
proc sql noprint;
  select 
    cycle_start_date
  , cycle_start_date format=date11.
  into
    :cycle_start_date_value trimmed
  , :cycle_start_date_literal trimmed
  from
    shared1.parameters
  ;

%put &=cycle_start_date_value;
%put &=cycle_start_date_literal;

/* 
 * will log the macro variable value as follows:
 * CYCLE_START_DATE_VALUE=22349 and
 * CYCLE_START_DATE_LITERAL=10-MAR2021
 */

data ...
  set ...;
  where date >= &cycle_start_date; *resolve parameter as text representation of a SAS date value (integer);
...

title "Cycle starts: &cycle_start_date_literal";

proc print data=...; * title in output shows human readable part of date;
run;
```

---

Another approach is to use a common source code file that is `%include`d by others.  You would edit or recreate the parameters file by whatever process you want.

**parameters.sas**

```
  %let cycle_start_date = 10-Mar-2021;
```

**use**

```
%include 'parameters.sas';

data ...
  set ...;
  where date >= "&cycle_start_date"D; *resolve parameter as part of date literal;
...

title "Cycle starts: &cycle_start_date";

proc print data=...; * title in output shows human readable part of date literal;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be to put the date from the `cycle_start_date` table that is in the shared library `shared1` into a macro-variable `date` that will be used in your data step to filter the `ytd_table` table based on the `entry_date` variable.

```
proc sql noprint;
select cycle_start_date into :date 
from shared1.cycle_start_date;
quit;

data mtd_table;
set ytd_table;
where entry_date > &date.;
run;
```